# javascript length returns unfinded

Tags: javascript, html

why when I want, to check webAdress length it's returents me unfinded,but don't the length?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             function myFunction() {
                 var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress');
               alert(String(webAdress.legnth));
}
```

Comment: The `legnth` in your question is a typo i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct `document.getElementById` always return single element if exist. You should not use same id for multiple element.

`webAdress` is dom element not an array.

if you want to check length with some specific elements use class
eg.

```
var webAdress = document.getElementsByClassName('webAdress');
alert(webAdress.length);
```

if you want to check content length of webAdress:

```
var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress');
alert(webAdress.innerHTML.length);
```

Comment: so what should i type to return the length of the string?

Comment: `webAddress.innerHTML.length`  or `webAddress.innerText.length`

Comment: If its an input element, you can use `webAddress.value`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get how many control are available that name is webAdress then below function is correct. But if you want to get string length of webAdress field then you must have value attributes of javascirpt function as per given below

```
function myFunction() {
     var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress');
   alert(String(webAdress.legnth));
}

function myFunction() {
     var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress').value;
   alert(String(webAdress.legnth));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="webAdress">
<input type="button" value="check" onClick="myFunction()">​


        function myFunction() {
            var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress').value;
            alert(webAdress.length);
        }
```

If you try this example, there was issue in spell.

UPDATE: I added same script yo a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/Rk7ht/1/